# How to get the input value in pysimplegui and pass it to openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl, pysimplegui

I want to get the value of input '-Name-' and pass it to value in openpyxl

but the problem is (value = '-name-') openpyxl did not accept it.

```
test.cell(row=8,column=16).value='-Name-'
```

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from openpyxl import load_workbook, workbook



wb = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
test = wb.active


layout = [[sg.Text('name of employe')],      
         [sg.Text('Name', size=(15,1)), sg.InputText(key='-Name-')],
         [sg.Button('OK'), sg.Button('Exit')]]


test.cell(row=8,column=16).value='-Name-'


window = sg.Window('title', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
    elif event == 'OK':
        wb.save('test.xlsx')


window.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to save is not the string `'-Name-'`, but the content of Input element after event which is `'OK'` button clicked here.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from openpyxl import load_workbook, workbook


wb = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
test = wb.active

layout = [[sg.Text('name of employe')],
         [sg.Text('Name', size=(15,1)), sg.InputText(key='-Name-')],
         [sg.Button('OK'), sg.Button('Exit')]]

window = sg.Window('title', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
    elif event == 'OK':
        value = values['-Name-']
        test.cell(row=8, column=16).value = value
        wb.save('test.xlsx')

window.close()
```